# Second monitor gaining and losing detection constantly

Tags: windows-8, drivers, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, vga

I'm not sure if this is a hardware issue or software but from initial tests seems to be software related or hardware but not the monitor itself.

The situation: I have a slightly old sony vaio laptop with an external monitor plugged in via vga.
The problem: The primary display, being the external monitor, gets "undetected" and "redetected" every second, constantly, until I disconnect the monitor entirely. The computer is basically completely unusable because it keeps changing the primary display.

Connecting the monitor to another pc (also via vga) works so I don't think the problem lies in the monitor or the vga cable. The only culprits I can think of are the video card (ati) or some driver issue (reinstalling them though seems to have no effect).

I'm running windows 8.1, 13.9 mobility ati drivers, 64bit.
If you have any idea what might be the problem, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Your only other available test is to reinstall Windows. You may want to try installing Windows 7 or 8, even just temporarily, to see if it's an issue with compatibility between the video card/drivers with Windows 8.1.

Comment: I can't recall for sure but I think I had the same issue develop when I have win8 installed, but I then reverted to 7 and I don't think it happened then. What's even weirder is that the issue seems to develop randomly as the setup was working fine for about a month now.

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of drivers causing this sort of behavior.  This sounds like hardware.  Whether the GPU is modular or built-in into the motherboard is probably beside the point.  You will either have to get it repaired in which case the person repairing will be able to determine which is the faulty part, or get it replaced which might be more difficult than you think.  Might be worth looking into using a USB video output adaptor.

http://www.startech.com/usb-video-adapters

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case; then again the laptop is stretching it a bit in the hardware department. Maybe it's just time to buy a new one.